# .remove(); jquery appended div

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

### http://jsfiddle.net/VTD9P/2/

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("body").append('<div  class="vidminclose">X</div>');
});
$(".vidminclose").click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

​
​why is it when i click the `div.miniclose` it is that it wont remove... and what is a way of getting around it. and i have looked at similar questions but i can't seem to fit their solutions to fix my problem.

Comment: This must be the most recurrent question ever ;) Look at live, delegate or the new `on`.

Comment: i know @Robin . I have used very complicated jquery and come up with solutions, but never have i ever needed (until now) needed to do this.

Comment: By recurrent, i think Robin means it comes up about a hundred times every single day, and a search on SO after delegating events for elements that do not exist, would probably have given you a gazzilion answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.vidmeclose` does not exist to have the click event bound to it when `.click` is fired since it is appended to the DOM later.  You need to do one of two things (and this also depends on your jQuery version).

## Solution #1

```
$("#button").click(...
    $("body").append(...
    $(".vidmeclose").click(...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VTD9P/4/

## Solution #2

```
$("button").click(...

$("body").on('click', '.vidmeclose', function () ...
```

Note that it could be useful to use a more specific selector in the second example, if it's available.

http://jsfiddle.net/VTD9P/5/

Comment: @Loktar, hehe, answer first and fiddle later.

Answer (score 0):

it's because vidminclose does not exist yet.   need to use `live` (older jquery) or `on` (newer jquery).